# How to manage Unity3D Instances/singletons

Tags: unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, ioc-container

*Note: I have many years of development experience, but I'm a total beginner in Unity.*

I was wondering **what is the best practice for managing your GameObjects across scenes**?

As you may know, each Scene has an Hierarchy tree with actual instances, lets say that I have a ScoreManager game object that I want to instantiate only one time, but I want to avoid the singleton pattern. (As it's a bad practice). Let's also say that the ScoreManager requires an instance of LevelsManager and so on...

One solution that I'm familiar with is **Dependency Injection**, but I did find any tutorial that uses it. All the tutorials that I see instantiate GameObjects in the Hierarchy tree, links other GameObjects via a public propery... which can count as a way to do Dependency Injection, but only for the current scene...

So, do you have a good practice that you use and love?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

[@Shogunivar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5610030/shogunivar) suggested [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html), the problem with that is that you should put only one GameObject in the first scene hierarchy, for example **WelcomeScene**, it will persist in all the future scene that were loaded.

The problem with that is that you might want to test (Press Play) say on **Level01Scene** that requires this GameObject to exist, but it's not there, you must first load the **WelcomeScene** that has this GameObject in the Heirarchy.

Putting the same GameObject also on **Level01Scene** will cause it to get duplicated, and will never destroy...

To solve this duplication, the only solution (That I know of) is to use Singleton. It's not "the-end-of-the-world", but this is the purpose of this question. Any other best-practice to handle this issue (In Unity)?

Comment: Check out [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) It will allow you to pass over gameobjects through different scenes.

Comment: DontDestroyOnLoad prevents me from testing the current edited scene...

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it is preventing you from testing?

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: If it's only a problem during testing you could just make a [prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) out of it. This way you can just add and remove it real quick when you just want to test a scene, while still using DontDestroyOnLoad for your actual application. If that is too much effort then the only thing I can think of is checking if it exists (so basically making a singleton out of it)

Comment: @gilamran : If you are interested by Dependency Injection, the Unity inspector can be seen as a Dependency Injector by itself. If you have not seen it take a look at [this blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/11/20/making-cool-stuff-with-scriptableobjects/) and the [talk at Unite Austin by Ryan Hipple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3iHhE_Kk) who uses scriptable objects in a very elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zenject](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject) is really powerful. There is some great documentation on their Github page as well that explains a lot. This is a great way to manage global bindings.

However, if you want something far simpler, you could inherit from a singleton class. Most people will advise against it, but it does work and it is super easy.

```
public class SingletonController : MonoBehaviour {
 public static SingletonController Instance;

 private void Awake() {
  if (Instance != null) {
   Destroy(gameObject);
  } else {
   Instance = this;
  }
 }
}
```